# Stackoverflow q&a print view

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

Hi Stackoverflowers,

I wanted to know if anyones aware if the Stackoverflow team is working on a printable view for the Q&A's.  It'd even be cooler to have it output to PDF format for a very nice print job.  :)

It would be awesome to have a feature like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [StackPrint](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) - one of the many awesome apps developed using the Stack Overflow API...

Comment: Thank you very much!  I would give you a 1 up, but don't have enough points here on meta.

Comment: Nevermind, automagically I got a +100 for my associated accounts. Kudos to SE